# How do you do an automated migration from TWiki to XWiki?

Tags: migration, wiki, twiki

I have been trying out various wiki technologies to replace the twiki install we are currently running at my workplace (it's just getting too slow and having tried a number of plugins, I have failed to make it fast enough).

One that looks good is XWiki.

Are there any tools out there to support this migration?

Or is this more a scripting question for stackoverflow?

Examples of differences:

XWiki:

> ```
> 1 Heading 1   
> 1.1 Heading 2 
> 1.1.1 Heading 3   
> 1.1.1.1 Heading 4
> ```

TWiki:

> ```
> ---+ Heading 1
> ---++ Heading 2
> ---+++ Heading 3
> ---++++ Heading 4
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know XWiki is working on a [Wiki Importer](http://gsoc.myxwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Import+Export+other+wikis/Import+Export+from+any+other+Wiki) ("à la" [Conluence UWC](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFEXT/Universal+Wiki+Converter)), the version 1.0 has been released, but I don't know what it includes. I'd suggest asking this question on [XWiki's user list](http://dev.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Community/MailingLists).

FYI, starting with XWiki Enterprise 1.7, XWiki provides other syntaxes in addition to XWiki's syntax: MediaWiki, Confluence, JSPWiki, Creole, **TWiki** and more. Actually, it's even possible to use TWiki's syntax as [default](http://platform.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/AdminGuide/Configuration#HConfiguringWikiSyntaxesanddefaultSyntax). This might be interesting in your context (but doesn't solve the automated import issue).

Comment: Magic, I had no idea about the syntax configuration!
I've tried it for a couple of simple pages and it doesn't work that well... but is certainly readable (headers are shown as text, but at least they are not strike-thru'd

Comment: If you are facing some glitches, report them, I'm sure the XWiki guys will fix them. http://jira.xwiki.org